# Removing Unwanted Characters after numbers in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to clean a DataFrame and I have come across an annoying snag. When I web-scrape the HTML wiki table in, I am left with the reference numbers/letters and I am trying to remove them.

This is what the part of the dataframe I currently have looks like:

```
Output:
[1.] 19.5million[1][b]
[2.] 16million[5][6][7][d]
[3.] 13.2million[11][e]
```

This is what I would like for it to look like:

```
Output:
[1.] 19.5
[2.] 16
[3.] 13.2
```

I have tried to use `str.replace` & `str.strip` but I always end up only getting either the millions removed or nothing at all. I feel like I'm missing the correct characters to receive the response I want.

Comment: To be 100% fair, I believe there is something wrong with your scraper, it is a bit strange you are getting all those values, could you try to scrape a more specific value perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

If always there is a million after the number you want, you can use `str.split('million')[0]`. This would give you desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse all the lines using the following `regex`:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("(\[\d+\.\]) ([\d\.]+)")

line = "[1.] 19.5million[1][b]"

" ".join(pattern.findall(line)[0])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
'[1.] 19.5'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
In [20]: testdata
Out[20]:
['[1.] 19.5million[1][b]',
 '[2.] 16million[5][6][7][d]',
 '[3.] 13.2million[11][e]']

In [21]: for row in testdata:
    ...:     print(row.split('million')[0])
    ...:
[1.] 19.5
[2.] 16
[3.] 13.2
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex and apply it to your pandas series using pandas string method [extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

```
pattern = r"^(\d+\.?\d*)"

df["foo"] = df["foo"].str.extract(pattern)
```

Explaination of the regex

- ^ match the start of the string
- (  start capture group
- \d+ match at least one digit
- .? optionally match a . (need \ to escape as . is a special character in regex)
- \d* match any number of digits
- ) end capture group